# Rotate raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, rotate

I have two raster datasets of Antarctica, however, they do not match spatially as one of the raster should be rotates 90 degrees. Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the rasters have correct location but one of them is rotated, then you can georeference incorrect raster based on the correct (georeferenced) one. You can either use `Raster -> Georeferencer` tool to do the job, or use [Freehand raster georeferencer plugin](http://gvellut.github.io/FreehandRasterGeoreferencer/) which has the function to rotate the raster data.

[image]

You can download Freehand raster georeferencer plugin from the plugin manager.

Comment: I tried this, but this tools gives an error: "CRS does not match: Found existing georeferencing in raster but its CRS does not match the CRS of the map. Unable to reproject." I checked in the layer properties and the CRS is defined as Antarctic Polar Stereographic (EPSG: 3031)