# Rotate raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster, rotate

I have a raster layer that I am trying to rotate so it is level in QGIS. I have attempted the solution offered here ([Rotate raster in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330947/rotate-raster-in-qgis)) but without success; the data disappears when I open the layer in the Freehand raster georeferencer.

Is anyone able to provide an alternative method that rotates the layer? I am aware of the 'rotate' feature bottom-right of the QGIS window, but I want something that rotates the data itself - not just the view.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a raster you want to rotate "so it is level"? Can you explain? If you just want to geocode it, no need to rotate manually, the georeferencer will handly this automatically.

Comment: There is a `GRASS` tool called `i.rotate`. I didn't try it myself but it might help you. (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/addons/i.rotate.html)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. By 'so it is level', I mean rotate some 25-30 degrees so that it is perpendicular.

Comment: OK, so why rotate the image separately when you anyhow want to georeference? In this process, the image is rotated the correct amount anyhow. I don't understand what you want to achieve by rotating.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 'geocoding'?

Comment: Sorry, I mean georeferencing, not geocoding: place a map (e.g. old, scanned map, satellite image etc.) on a reference map, like a OpenStreetMap basemap, see. In this process, the input map is scaled, rotated, skewed, distorted, warped etc. as long until it fits on the reference map: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html

Comment: I think to get the help you need you should tell us a bit more about what you have and what you want to achieve finally and why, at what step, you need the rotation. There are many ways to "rotate" a layer, how you do it depends on the very task.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this topic. So what I undertook some terrestrial laser scans (TLS) of a river bed. The TLS data is not georectified, and it does not have any locational data. I then inputted the data in QGIS as a vector, before turning the data into a raster. The transformation can be applied to either the vector, or the raster, it doesn't matter to me. The reason I want to rotate it is because I need to know the riverbed characteristics (such as the sediment orientation). If the layer is not straight, then I will not get accurate information about the sediment orientation.

Comment: So you should **georeference** your data - in newer QGIS versions possible for raster and vector (menu layer > georeferencer) , in older versions for rasters only (menu raster  > georeferencer). It will do what you want

Comment: Okay thanks for your help, I will give this a go.